# I have a oneToOne relationship in jpa that sets JoinColumn id to null, although it has a defined number

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, persistence

I have to classes representing two tables in my database. The first is Organizations and the second one Address. Their connection is a OneToOne starting from the Organizations towards the Addresses.
Organizations have PK: orgId which they share with Addresses and is how they are connected.

Organizations:

```
@Entity(name = "Organizations")
@Table(name = "Organizations")
public class Organizations
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "orgId", nullable = false, unique = true, precision = 0)
    private Integer orgId;

    // foreign tables
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "orgAdd",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        optional = false)
    private Address address;
```

Address:

```
@Entity(name = "Address")
@Table(name = "Address")
public class Address
{
    @Id
    private Integer orgId;  

    // foreign tables
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
        @JoinColumn(name = "orgId", updatable = false, unique = true)
    private Organizations orgAdd;
```

I create both a newOrg and a newAdd and put the address in the org, which I check with a toString call to see if everything is fine.

But when I call persistence and try to insert the values jpa nulls the orgId in Address throwing the following exception:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'orgId' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO Address (alterLoc, city, cntry, number, state, street, zip, orgId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [Pristol, America, 2, 5, Kentucky, England, 12343, null]
```

Comment: The address must have an organization. That's where it gets its ID from. that's the owner side of the association. And JoinColumn shouldn't be there. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived

Comment: It has as I have shown in the second code block:
```private Organizations orgAdd;```

Comment: None of your code blocks shows how you create and persist your entities. All you've said is "I create both a newOrg and a newAdd and put the address in the org,". But you didn't say "and I also put the organization in the address", so I assume you didn't do that. And that's what you need to do.

Comment: ```Organizations newOrg = new Organizations(1, "kappa1", "kappa2", "kappa3");
     Address newAdd = new Address(1, 2, 3, "kappa4", "kappa5", "kappa6", "4", "kappa7");
     newOrg.setAddress(newAdd);```

But this is beside the point, as I create the classes correctly and they both have 1 as orgId, but JPA makes it null.

Comment: You need to set the organization of the address. You leave it null. So it's null, and the ID derived from it is null too. Add `newAdd.setOrganization(newOrg)`. If you still don't understand, I don't know what I can do anymore. It's explained, with an example and everything, in the documentation I linked to. Have you read it?

Comment: It worked ! First of all thank you so very much, I lost 2 hours of my life for this thing.
One thing I want to clarify so that I understand it, I have to put the objects both ways, and they have to match ? What I want to ask is how does jpa do the connection, because with what I did it had all the data to perform the insertion but it did not.

Comment: It didn't have all the data. The owning side of the association (the one which doesn't use the mappedBy attribute) is what matters to JPA, and you left that owning side null. But yes, in general, it's better to ensure the consistency on both sides: i the organization has an address, then that address should have the organization.

Comment: Thank you very much, you should make a comment so that I can like it :)